# sich verstecken

Tags: verb, verb-usage, reflexive

Why would you say, "Das Risiko für die israelischen Truppen ist dennoch sehr hoch, weil sie nicht genau wissen, wo Kämpfer versteckt, wo die Waffendepots sind, wo sich die Geiseln befinden. Die israelische Armee könnte im Häuserkampf hohe Verluste erleiden. Ich vermute, dass die Hamas das miteingeplant hat und bereit ist, dem israelischen Militär - selbst auf Kosten der eigenen Sicherheit - hohe Verluste zuzufügen." ?

Why do the Kämpfer versteckt instead of verstecken and where is the sich?
Stated otherwise, did they make a mistake?

Published at https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/asien/israel-hamas-gazastreifen-100.html

Answer (score 12):

It's an ellipsis.

> … nicht genau wissen, wo Kämpfer versteckt (sind), wo die Waffendepots **sind**, …

It's not a good ellipsis as otherwise you had understood it.

Answer (score 5):

The auxiliary phrase:

> ..., wo Kämpfer **sich** verstecken, ...

would be correct, and while you quote the reflexive form in the title, it does not appear below. In the phrase given, the verb *sind* serves a double duty, it belongs to *Kämpfer versteckt* and *Waffendepots*. I find that phrase not fully convincing, since it at least allows, that somebody else hid the combattants.

Comment: Well, especially in (para-) military command structures, it is very well possible the fighters actually didn't hide themselves, but *were hidden* by their command.